# Creating multiple cohort from the pivot table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, forecast

I have a requirement like below.

The initial information is a list of gross adds.

| 201910 | 201911 | 201912 | 202001 | 202002 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20000 | 30000 | 32000 | 40000 | 36000 |

I have a pivot table as below.

| 201910 | 201911 | 201912 | 202001 | 202002 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 2000 | 2400 | 3200 | 1800 |
| 500 | 400 | 300 | 200 | nan |
| 200 | 150 | 100 | nan | nan |
| 200 | 100 | nan | nan | nan |
| 160 | nan | nan | nan | nan |

Need to generate the report like below.

Cohort01:

| 5% |
| --- |
| 3% |
| 3% |
| 1% |
| 1% |
| 1% |

From Cohort02 onwards it will take the average of last value of cohort01.
Similarly for Cohort03 for both nan values it will take the average of corresponding values of cohort01 and cohort2.
Again while calculating for cohort04 it will take the average of previous two cohorts(cohort02 and cohort03 values) to add all three nan value.

Is there anyone who can provide me a solution on this in Python.

The report should be generated as below.

All cohorts should be created separately.

[image]

Comment: could you please add the whole expected output for the provided pivot table? not quite sure if it is clear how to "generate" the report. few more details would be nice

Comment: Hi Rabinzel, I have updated the output above. Kindly check and let me know if you need any additional details.

Comment: Hi @Rabinzel, Did you get the query. Do you have a solution for this ?

Comment: hey, yes I thought everything is clear after you added that additional table. But now I found something else which I can't explain. For the first cohort the results are `5, 3, 3, 1, 1` but when calculating the percentage of these values according to `20000` I don't get these percentage numbers. What am I missing

Comment: did my solution work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try it like this:

```
res = df.apply(lambda x: round(100/(df_gross.iloc[0]/x),1),axis=1)
print(res)

   201910  201911  201912  202001  202002
0     5.0     6.7     7.5     8.0     5.0
1     2.5     1.3     0.9     0.5     NaN
2     1.0     0.5     0.3     NaN     NaN
3     1.0     0.3     NaN     NaN     NaN
4     0.8     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN

for idx,col in enumerate(res.columns[1:],1):
    res[col] = res[col].fillna((res.iloc[:,max(idx-2,0)]+res.iloc[:,idx-1])/2)
print(res)

   201910  201911  201912  202001  202002
0     5.0     6.7    7.50   8.000  5.0000
1     2.5     1.3    0.90   0.500  0.7000
2     1.0     0.5    0.30   0.400  0.3500
3     1.0     0.3    0.65   0.475  0.5625
4     0.8     0.8    0.80   0.800  0.8000
```

Comment: Hi, There is an issue over here. Suppose if i have any null values(nan) in my dataframe in the upper rows then that is getting converted into a value, which i don't want. I just need the nan need to be converted below the diagonal. Please let me know if you got my point.

Comment: yes, got it. what happens if you have a null value above the diagonal and it should be used to calculate the mean() in that row? ...I will have another look into it, maybe I can fix that too.

Comment: in your example data you have same number of rows and columns and the number of NaNs increases by 1 each column. Is that in your real data always the same ?

Comment: Hi Rabinzel, I made little bit changes in your code and it worked out. Thank you very much for providing a great work around.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't mind to edit my answer with your additional changes to make it work. Consider voting/accepting my answer to close the question, it also helps me :)

Comment: Yep. I voted your answer.Thanks again for your help.